# cancancan auth in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

Im adding in cancancan to my app for authorisation, and ive can across a snag.

I have a voting system where as you cant vote on your on own entry but you can edit, delete etc.

So ive created a block inside the ability class.

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.present?
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all

    else
      can :vote, Entry do |entry|
        user.id != entry.user_id
      end
      can :manage, Entry, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Message, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Profile, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, User, user_id: user.id

    end

   can :read, :all

  end
 end
```

here is where im calling the can? method:

```
<% @entries.each do |x| %>

 <% if can? :vote, x %>
  <span class="text-green"> <%= link_to like_entry_path(x), method: :put, remote: true do %>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
  <% end %>
  </span>
  <span class="badge" id="upvote-count<%=x.id%>"><%= x.get_upvotes.size%></span>
  <span class="text-red"> <%= link_to unlike_entry_path(x), method: :put, remote: true do %>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <% end %>
  </span>
  <span class="badge" id="downvote-count<%=x.id%>"><%= x.get_downvotes.size%></span>
 <% else %>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-up text-grey"></i>
  <span class="badge"><%= x.get_upvotes.size%></span>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down text-grey"></i>
  <span class="badge"><%= x.get_downvotes.size%></span>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But its still printing the links when it shouldn't?

When debugging, On the first entry i check `user.id != entry.user_id` and its comes back as false, so i can vote on it, but in the second loop that same query comes back as true as it should do but the links still appear in the view?

To sum it up if that was a bit confusing, Two entries made to two different accounts but the voting links appear on both entries.

Comment: what if you swap `can :manage, Entry` and `can :vote, Entry` in the ability file?

Comment: Did you check your user and entry user id are correct in the database first?

Comment: @Thrasher yes ive checked the database,

Comment: @apneadiving Made no difference unfortunalty

Comment: is your user admin?

Comment: I have one admin user open and a normal user open, they both have all links showing. but admin has :manage, :all so i presume thats why on that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the ability like this:

```
cannot :vote, Entry if  user_id: user.id
```

Doc: [Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#only-for-object-attributes](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#only-for-object-attributes)

Comment: No its that the voting links are showing when they shouldn't, So the cancan ability isnt working for some reason

Comment: Do you know what i think thats got it, Im just going to run some more tests on the site!, You saved me i was literally pulling my hair about to uninstall cancancan for good!